# Read UTF-8 string from SQL Server & Display in VB6 Controls

Tags: sql-server, unicode, utf-8, vb6

I am trying to display UTF-8 charset (other than English language like Chinese or Japanese on the VB6 Controls) which is query result from SQL SERVER Database, whenever I am reading from the recordset its always giving '???' (Question Marks), I have gone through so many threads but unable to find anything which can help me to display Unicode chars on the VB6 controls which were get from recordset.

ADODB.Stream have the properties like charset, so we can set the charset as UTF-8. 
Do we have anything in the ADODB.Recordset also to read the UTF-8 chars from db?

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

Dim zConnectString As String
Dim zConnection As ADODB.Connection
Dim record As ADODB.Recordset
Dim zServerName As String
Dim zDBUser As String
Dim zDBPassword As String
Dim com As String
Dim data As String
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command

zServerName = SERVER_IP
zDBUser = USER
zDBPassword = PWD

zConnectString = "Provider=MSDASQL;Driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0; Server=" & zServerName & "; UID=" & zDBUser & ";PWD=" & zDBPassword
zConnectString = zConnectString & ";Network=DBMSSOCN"

Set zConnection = New ADODB.Connection
zConnection.ConnectionString = zConnectString
zConnection.CursorLocation = adUseClient


zConnection.Open

Dim rsRecCount As Integer

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = zConnection
cmd.CommandText = "select PU_Desc from [SOADB].[dbo].[Prod_Units_Base] where PU_Id =22"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

Set record = New ADODB.Recordset
record.CursorLocation = adUseServer

record.Open cmd, , adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly


rsRecCount = record.RecordCount

Dim StrUnicode As String


Dim x As String
While Not record.EOF
    x = record!PU_Desc 
    record.MoveNext
Wend
Text1.Text = x    
End Sub
```

Above is the Sample application, I am reading the recordset in x and getting value as '??'

Below is the Query, PU_Desc DataType = Nvarchar[100]

```
select PU_Desc from [SOADB].[dbo].[Prod_Units_Base] where PU_Id =22

PU_Desc = 锅炉
```

Comment: VB6 is Unicode internally but all user interface is ANSI (VB6 was written for Win 9x so isn't Unicode externally). So you need to do foreign ANSI stuff. I speak English so can't help. Any Unicode string you send to the UI will be converted to ANSI.

Comment: PS the conversion is based on system settings.

Comment: Yes, everyone knows VB6 is internally UNICODE and change to ANSI based on the Regional Locale, but if i want to make app as multi-language support without changing Locale. so could it be done just like Stream has CharSet properties, do we have any in the recordset?

Comment: There is a VB6 project "ActiveX CommonControls (Replacement of the MS common controls)" at http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?841929-VB6-ActiveX-CommonControls-(Replacement-of-the-MS-common-controls)

Comment: All controls from vbforums.com are unicode. Also try changing regional setting "Language for non-unicode programs" is you use standard VB6 controls.

Comment: I also recommend using the Common Controls replacement http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?698563-CommonControls-(Replacement-of-the-MS-common-controls)
As well as supporting unicode, they also support VisualStyles and are DPI-aware.

Comment: I am planning to replace the controls from VB6 dedefault to FM20.dll, but while preparing for the list the one of the control "TreeView" (its in Windows common control)  for my Project is not available in FM20. so can anyone suggest, from where can i get the "TreeView with Unicode SUPPORT". Thanks in Advance

Comment: Take a look at http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?325661-TreeView-supporting-Unicode-in-VB-6-0

Comment: @VB6 programming ,@smith  I had given a tried with replacement of MS Common with custom control as mentioned in http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?698563-CommonControls-(Replacement-of-the-MS-common-controls) , but this one also doesn't work, In my application  I am using some third party controls, and as usual some other MS controls  like MS Command controls, but this causing the crash of VB6. might be something is corrupting because we have to hack the VB6 to make it work custom controls, any comments on this ?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to display the data using controls (e.g.: Textbox) from this component:

```
Project -> Components -> Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library
```

And, the most important thing is assign the value directly from the Recordset.

Note: some of the properties are different, compared with the default controls (e.g.: Textbox)

Hope that helps :)